# Cabinets and baseboard splitting from wall

Tags: bathroom, cabinets, humidity

I recently noticed several places where my house seems to be breaking in two. Some baseboards seem to be detaching and the cabinets kind of falling.

The building is from the 70s and the house was remodeled in ~2013. Is this because of an old home issue or is it more severe?
I live in Florida near the water so lots of humidity in case that matters.

Comment: Pictures will help.  The cabinets might just not been screwed into the studs(just missed?) and the screws just in drywall, and the weight is just pulling them down(happen to me).  Check your foundation for any funny/odd/new looking cracks.

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer.

Comment: Not enough information was provided to answer this question accurately. Please include the make and model of all devices and equipment, photos, diagrams, drawings, and any other information that might help people provide an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

That can be signs of termites.  Especially in Fla.  Is the home block or frame construction?  Both can have termite issues.  Have you seen any pinholes in any walls and is there any piles of what look like sawdust anywhere?
If you can pull a section of baseboard away from the wall. Report what you find there for a better idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should determine whether that is just a cosmetic/finish issue such as the trim and cabinets being installed lazily, or a structural issue such as the house itself subsiding and causing the walls to move and flex.

Check all your doors and windows.  Do they operate the same as they always have, i.e. no new issues with binding or scraping anywhere?  If nothing has changed there, you can probably safely rule out structural issues and focus on the potential that whoever installed the trim and cabinets might have screwed them into drywall instead of framing, etc.  Those are easy enough to fix if that is the case.

Pictures would help us identify where the movement is.